# Apache Flink's Iterative Stream won't loop

Tags: mapreduce, apache-flink, flink-streaming, connected-components

I'm implementing the connected components algorithm using Flink's DataStream API, since there is not yet an implementation of it using this API.
For this algorithm, I'm separating the data by tumbling windows. So, for each window, I`m trying to compute the algorithm independently.

My problem comes from the iterative character of the algorithm. I implemented the data pipeline that I wanted for the interactions (the step data pipeline), which consists on FlatMaps, 1 Join, 1 ProcessWindow and 1 Filter. However, it seems that the stream I wanted to feedback the loop is not actually being fed back to the beginning of the loop, because the algorithm does not iterate. I suspect it is not possible to do it if the original iteration datastream was joined with another stream (even though the latter was originated by a flatMap on the former).

The code that I`m using is as follows:

```
    //neigborsList = Datastream of <Vertex, [List of neighbors], label>
IterativeStream< Tuple3<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>, Integer> > beginning_loop = neigborsList.iterate(maxTimeout);

//Emits tuples Vertices and Labels for every vertex and its neighbors

DataStream<Tuple2<Integer,Integer> > labels = beginning_loop
        //Datastream of <Vertex, label> for every neigborsList.f0 and element in neigborsList.f1
        .flatMap( new EmitVertexLabel() ) 
        .keyBy(0)
        .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(windowSize)))
        .minBy(1)               
        ;


DataStream<Tuple4<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>, Integer, Integer>> updatedVertex = beginning_loop                
            //Update vertex label with the results from the labels reduction
            .join(labels)
            .where("vertex")
            .equalTo("vertex")
            .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(windowSize)))
            .apply(new JoinFunction<Tuple3<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>,Integer>, Tuple2<Integer,Integer>, Tuple4<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>,Integer,Integer>>() {

                @Override
                public Tuple4<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>,Integer,Integer> join(
                        Tuple3<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>, Integer> arg0, Tuple2<Integer, Integer> arg1)
                        throws Exception {
                    int hasConverged = 1;
                    if(arg1.f1.intValue() < arg0.f2.intValue() )
                    {
                        arg0.f2 = arg1.f1;
                        hasConverged=0;
                    }
                    return new Tuple4<>(arg0.f0,arg0.f1,arg0.f2,new Integer(hasConverged));
                }                       

            })

            //Disseminates the convergence flag if a change was made in the window
            .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(windowSize)))
            .process(new ProcessAllWindowFunction<Tuple4<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>,Integer,Integer>,Tuple4<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>, Integer, Integer>,TimeWindow >() {

                @Override
                public void process(
                        ProcessAllWindowFunction<Tuple4<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>, Integer, Integer>, Tuple4<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>, Integer, Integer>, TimeWindow>.Context ctx,
                        Iterable<Tuple4<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>, Integer, Integer>> values,
                        Collector<Tuple4<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>, Integer, Integer>> out) throws Exception {

                    Iterator<Tuple4<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>, Integer, Integer>> iterator = values.iterator();
                    Tuple4<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>, Integer, Integer> element;

                    int hasConverged= 1;
                    while(iterator.hasNext())
                    {
                        element = iterator.next();
                        if(element.f3.intValue()>0)
                        {
                            hasConverged=0;
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    //Re iterate and emit the values on the correct output
                    iterator = values.iterator();                           
                    Integer converged = new Integer(hasConverged);
                    while(iterator.hasNext())
                    {
                        element = iterator.next();
                        element.f3 = converged;
                        out.collect(element);

                    }                                                   
                }
            })              

            ;


DataStream<Tuple3<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>, Integer>> feed_back = updatedVertex
        .filter(new NotConvergedFilter())                               
        //Remove the finished convergence flag
        //Transforms the Tuples4 to Tuples3 so that it becomes compatible with beginning_loop
        .map(new RemoveConvergeceFlag())
        ;


beginning_loop.closeWith(feed_back);

//Selects the windows that have already converged
DataStream<?> convergedWindows = updatedVertex
        .filter(new ConvergedFilter() );


convergedWindows.print()
.setParallelism(1)
.name("Sink to stdout");
```

At the end of the execution convergedWindows does not receives any tupple (because the algorithm could not converge with only 1 iteration).
If I print the beginning_loop, I see the initial tupples and the tupples from feed_back resultant from the fist iteration. But, nothing else than that.

So, summarizing my question, could this be a limitation of Flink? If so, do you know a different way of updating the vertices labels after the initial reduction, one that is not based on joins?

PS. I'm using Flink 1.3.3